# Why is it that a DC magnetic field induces a voltage on a conductor rotating inside of the field?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

I'm having trouble getting a clear description as to exactly why the conductor must be rotating, and how flux induces voltage.

Comment: If you want to _understand_ the material quantitatively, I'd recommend taking a look at the 2nd volume of Feynman's Lecture series. It's now available on the web: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/ But a clue would be for you to think about what relativity means regarding the propagation of electric fields being limited by c. Or see this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity And pay particular attention to \$\varphi\$ and the A-field description there, which is the far more important bit to understand. (The classical E and B isn't.)

Answer (score 3):

> How flux induces voltage?

No, flux doesn't induce voltage. A change in flux with respect to time induces voltage.

> Flux = B x S x cos(theta)

where B = Magnetic field

S = Area

theta = Angle between area element and magnetic field

> Voltage = change in flux / change in time

It means either the area or field or the angle between the two should be changing w.r.t time in order to be able to generate a voltage. In practical applications, its not possible to change the loop area continuously and its easier to have a constant magnetic field. So, the only option left is to change the angle between the area loop and the magnetic field, which can be done by connecting the area loop to a turbine which can further be driven by air or falling water stream etc.

Now, if you are looking for "why does it happen?", I'd say it's the law of nature which has been proven to work over time. When any of these changes, it exerts a force on the electrons and make it behave in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of the universe. If a conductor is exposed to a magnetic field that is changing with time, whether due to motion or some other reason, the mobile charges in the conductor will experience an electro-motive force (EMF, or Voltage). Technically, the conductor does not need to rotate or move. It could be that the field moves. Or the field could simply change (for example if it is caused by an electromagnet, or the winding in a motor).

I could say that it is "because of the Lorentz Force, or because of Maxwell's equations" but I feel that is not a real answer to your question. You may want to google those terms, though.

Comment: Alternatives: It's how God made it :-)  | Because. | ...